# Synchronize pool of workers - Python and multiproccessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, synchronization, multiprocessing, igraph

I want to make an synchronized simulation of graph coloring. To create the graph (tree) I am using `igraph` package and to synchronization I am using for the first time `multiprocessing` package. I built a graph where each node has attributes: `label`, `color` and `parentColor`. To color the tree I excecute the following function (I am not giving the full code because it is very long, and I think not necessary to solve my problem):

```
def sixColor(self):
        root = self.graph.vs.find("root")
        root["color"] = self.takeColorFromList(root["label"])
        self.sendToChildren(root)
        lista = []
        for e in self.graph.vs():
            lista.append(e.index)
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(len(lista))
        p.map(fun, zip([self]*len(lista), lista),chunksize=300) 


    def process_sixColor(self, id):
        v = self.graph.vs.find(id)
        if not v["name"] == "root":
            while True:
                if v["received"] == True:
                    v["received"] = False
                    #------------Part 1-----------
                    self.sendToChildren(v)
                    self.printInfo()
                    #-----------Part 2-------------
                    diffIdx = self.compareLabelWithParent(v)
                    if not diffIdx == -1:
                        diffIdxStr = str(bin(diffIdx))[2:]
                        charAtPos = (v["label"][::-1])[diffIdx]
                        newLabel = diffIdxStr + charAtPos
                        v["label"] = newLabel
                        self.sendToChildren(v)
                        colorNum = int(newLabel,2)
                        if colorNum in sixColorList:
                            v["color"] = self.takeColorFromList(newLabel)
                            self.printGraph()
                            break
```

I want to have that each node (except root) is calling function `process_sixColor` synchronously in parallel and will not evaluate `Part 2`before `Part 1` will be made by all nodes. But I notice that this is not working properly and some nodes are evaluating before every other node will execute `Part 1`. How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of a `multiprocessing.Queue` and a `multiprocessing.Event` object to synchronize the workers. Make the main process create a `Queue` and an `Event` and pass both to all the workers. The `Queue` will be used by the workers to let the main process know that they are finished with part 1. The `Event` will be used by the main process to let all the workers know that all the workers are finished with part 1. Basically,

- the workers will call `queue.put()` to let the main process know that they have reached part 2 and then call `event.wait()` to wait for the main process to give the green light.
- the main process will repeatedly call `queue.get()` until it receives as many messages as there are workers in the worker pool and then call `event.set()` to give the green light for the workers to start with part 2.

This is a simple example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing import Event, Process, Queue

def worker(identifier, queue, event):
    # Part 1
    print("Worker {0} reached part 1".format(identifier))

    # Let the main process know that we have finished part 1
    queue.put(identifier)

    # Wait for all the other processes
    event.wait()

    # Start part 2
    print("Worker {0} reached part 2".format(identifier))

def main():
    queue = Queue()
    event = Event()
    processes = []
    num_processes = 5

    # Create the worker processes
    for identifier in range(num_processes):
        process = Process(target=worker, args=(identifier, queue, event))
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()

    # Wait for "part 1 completed" messages from the processes
    while num_processes > 0:
        queue.get()
        num_processes -= 1

    # Set the event now that all the processes have reached part 2
    event.set()

    # Wait for the processes to terminate
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to use this in a production environment, you should think about how to handle errors that occur in part 1. Right now if an exception happens in part 1, the worker will never call `queue.put()` and the main process will block indefinitely waiting for the message from the failed worker. A production-ready solution should probably wrap the entire part 1 in a `try..except` block and then send a special error signal in the queue. The main process can then exit immediately if the error signal is received in the queue.